# chart.js Scale Label not working Chart js in Angular 14

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

```js
public barChartOptions: any = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Counts',
        },
      },
    ],
    xAxes: [
      {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Locale',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I try the above code to add the scale label by not showing the scale label .I cannot able to add scaleLabel in bar charts, any way to add scaleLabel in X and Y,currently I used the  version- Angular is 14.0 and chart.js is 3.9.1

Thanks in Advance

[I want this type scalelabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6hOo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your scales as 2 arrays, this is V2 syntax, in V3 all scales are their own object within the `scales` object where the key is the ID of the scale. So changing your config to this will resolve the issue:

```js
scales: {
  y: {
    grid: {
      display: false,
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Counts',
    },
  },
  x: {
    grid: {
      display: false,
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Locale',
    },
  },
}
```

For all changes between V2 and V3 please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Comment: Hi LeeLenalee,Thanks for solution,That works cool